# Back-up my /Data folder in my c# project

Tags: c#, xml, save

as a starter of c# (And honestly not really loving the visual express c# environment) I'm in need of a back-up function to finish off my program.

I have 4 xml files in the /Data folder (In my project's root)
Now, what I want to do is back these files up in a file-save sense.

When a user clicks the "Back-up 1.xml!" button I want the program to open a saveDialog which automatically saves a pre-defined XML file (/Data/1.xml), to wherever the user wants, under whatever name the user wants.

However, I just cannot get googled how to make c# preselect that file. I only get these plugins from MSDN (which isn't very usefull either)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to copy a file from one location to another one.

Here is another StackOverflow thread that looks similarly to yours:
[Copy a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881450/c-sharp-copy-a-file-to-another-location-with-a-different-name)

Esentially, the only thing you need to do:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(oldPathAndName, newPathAndName);
```

You can get newPathAndName from user input. You know oldPathAndName already.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot test it right now but I will in a few hours. Anyway I believe you to be right. This should work.